# Correct including third part .framework to the Qt project

Tags: c++, macos, qt, sdl

I have an third part framework SDL.framework that I download from official site and I have a trouble with using this library.

I've copied the SDL.framework to the project ./library folder and include it as follows:

```
LIBS += -F$$PWD/library -framework SDL
INCLUDEPATH += library/SDL.framework/Headers
```

It compiles fine but when I'm truing to run the application can't find this framework:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Documents/build/project.app/Contents/MacOS/project
  Reason: image not found
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

I put the SDL.framework to the folder project.app/Contents/Frameworks  but application doesn't start anyway.

It seems that the paths to the libs is correct:

```
otool -L project.app/Contents/MacOS/project
project.app/Contents/MacOS/project:
    @rpath/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 12.4.0)
    @rpath/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtMultimediaWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimediaWidgets (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtMultimedia.framework/Versions/5/QtMultimedia (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtSql.framework/Versions/5/QtSql (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtSerialPort.framework/Versions/5/QtSerialPort (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.6.0, current version 5.6.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

Where can be problem?

Comment: SDL is completely unnecessary if you are already using Qt

Comment: There different ways of handling additional dependencies to your project:for instance copy with QMAKE_POST_LINK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631084/create-dir-copy-files-with-qmake

Comment: SDL is completely necessary while Qt doesn't have classes to communicate with joysticks.

Comment: There is no problem with copying framework to the .app/Contents/Frameworks. The problem is that application doesn't see framework in .app/Contents/Frameworks folder.

Comment: What makes you think that the source code that supposed to use SDL is correct then? If it is correct then what would be the right directory for SDL files relative to executable?