# How to automatically install my plugin to "plugins" directory after build?

Tags: qt, installation, qmake

Now it building successfully, but I need to copy it in destination directory by hand. I want to automate this process, but not so familiar with qmake (prefer cmake instead).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Custom Targets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets) feature.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631084/create-dir-copy-files-with-qmake) also can help you.